# .htaccess 301 redirect with regex with pagination

Tags: .htaccess, pagination, http-status-code-301

I  am trying hard to do this redirection from last 7 days .

**My source urls are**

```
example.com/computer-science/test/mcqs/data-mining/questions/191/1.html
example.com/computer-science/test/mcqs/data-mining/questions/191/2.html
example.com/computer-science/test/mcqs/data-mining/questions/191/3.html
```

....
.....
.....

**Destination URLs**

```
example.com/ugc-net-computer-science/cs-practice-questions/database/data-mining/
example.com/ugc-net-computer-science/cs-practice-questions/database/data-mining/page/2 
example.com/ugc-net-computer-science/cs-practice-questions/database/data-mining/page/3
```

am using below rule for redirection-

```
Redirect 301 /computer-science/test/mcqs/data-mining/questions/191/1.html https://example.com/ugc-net-computer-science/cs-practice-questions/database/data-mining/
```

But not able to redirect subsequent pages, tried many regex, but all in vein

I have more then 2k such URLS.